# Why is there a NPE on @Injectable class

Tags: jmockit

I have a class(looks something like this) I'm trying to test.

```
@Component
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource extends BaseResource {
    @Autowired UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Path("register")
    public User registerUser(User user){
        ...
        User registeredUser = userService.register(user);
        ...
        return registeredUser;
    }
}
```

The test looks like this.

```
public class UserResourceTest {
    @Tested UserResource userResource;
    @Injectable UserService userService;
    @Mocked BaseResource baseResource;

    @Test
    public void registerShouldDoSomething(){
        User user = new User();
        final User registerResult = new User();
        ...
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            userService.register((User)any); result = registerResult;
        }};
        userResource.registerUser(user);
        ...
    }
}
```

For some reason in the tested class, userService is null and throwing a NPE when register is called on it (UserService is a class not interface/abstract btw).  I'm wondering if perhaps some of the annotations(javax or Spring) may be clashing with JMockit or something(Although I've tried removing them)?

I've tried switching the injectable to just @Mocked, and I've tried removing it and having it be a @Mocked test method param. Nothing seems to be solving the NPE.

Comment: Works fine for me, no NPE. Is it using JUnit or TestNG? Which version? What is the version of the JDK/JRE? What version of JMockit?

Comment: JUnit 4.11 java 1.7, JMockit 1.13. Can you think of any reason a Mocked or Injectable would be null? The odd thing is, the Mocked BaseResource is working and can be mocked, but something with that UserService doesn't liked to be mocked.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with these versions; no idea how it can happen, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure if it helps at all but I've switched to just using Deencapsulation.setField(userResource,userService); on each test and that seems to have worked. Seems a bit hacky but oh well.

Comment: @Rogério https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/103 fixed the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using reflection to manually set the @Injectable fields in the @Tested class

```
public class UserResourceTest {
    @Tested UserResource userResource;
    @Injectable UserService userService;
    @Mocked BaseResource baseResource;

    @Test
    public void registerShouldDoSomething(){
        Deencapsulation.setField(userResource,userService); //This line
        User user = new User();
        final User registerResult = new User();
        ...
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            userService.register((User)any); result = registerResult;
        }};
        userResource.registerUser(user);
        ...
    }
}
```

Still not sure what the bug is, but this works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was mixing Spring annotations - Autowired with Java Resource. If you mix them only Java will be injected.
For more details please take a look at:
mockit.internal.expectations.injection.InjectionPoint

mockit.internal.expectations.injection.FieldInjection

especially discardFieldsNotAnnotatedWithJavaxInjectIfAtLeastOneIsAnnotated method.

This is a dirty solution to the problem:

```
package mockit.internal.expectations.injection;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;


public class DirtyHack {

    static {
        try {
            setFinalStatic(InjectionPoint.class.getDeclaredField("WITH_INJECTION_API_IN_CLASSPATH"), false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, newValue);
    }
}
```

Then your test need to for example extends this class.